# Magento 2 : mocking `getParam()` in unit test not working

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit, mocks

I'm breaking my head for hours now over a simple thing I've done hundreds of times: mocking another model. Can anyone see what's wrong with this?

```
$mockedRequest = $this
    ->getMockForAbstractClass(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface::class);
$mockedRequest
    ->method('getParam')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap([['a', 'b']]));

var_dump($mockedRequest->getParam('a'));
```

You would expect the result to be `b` right? WRONG! It returns `NULL`! And I can't for the love of God figure out why...

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be so happy... It's probably a small thing, but I can't see it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getParam` method accepts 2 parameters, the second one defaulting to `null`

```
public function getParam($key, $defaultValue = null);
```

`returnValueMap` works like this. the first N-1 values in the array are treated as the parameters for the method and the Nth value is the returned result.
So in your case it looks in the map for an array like this `[a, null, return value here]`.
And you don't have such an sub-array in your array map.  So it returns by default `null`.
make the return map like this:

```
->will($this->returnValueMap([['a', null, 'b']]));
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be something simple like this. Sounds like a case of code-blindness to me...